# Adding function to a HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to replace the following helper with its corresponding HTML in a view:

```
@Html.HelperTextBoxFor(model => model.Length, new { @ng_change = "changeArea()" })
```

I came up with this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="MyViewModel.Length" class="form-control" />
```

But I cannot find where to add the `new { @ng_change = "changeArea()"}`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Cant  you just do the same using Jquery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this `@ng_change="..."` is an Angular directive, this would look like this in an input tag:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="MyViewModel.Length" class="form-control" ng-change="changeArea()"/>
```

reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange

Answer (score 0):

You need to get back to the basics here, not sure why you can't figure it out.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="MyViewModel.Length" class="form-control" onchange="changeArea();" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Because I am a beginner!

Comment: No problem, you jump in the deep end here!